# How is a NFC session key created?

Tags: nfc

I was reading MIFARE DESFire EV1 document and noticed this:

> MIFARE DESFire EV1 and the reader device show in an encrypted way
>   that they possess the same secret which especially means the same key;
>   this *not only* confirms that both entities are permitted to perform
>   operations on each other *but also* creates a session key which can be
>   used to keep the further communication path secure; as the name
>   “session key” implicitly indicates, each time a new authentication
>   procedure is successfully completed a new key for further cryptographic
>   operations is generated

The *not only* part is easy to achieve. In the simplest form, 'server' can throw a random number at the card, and the card can reply with the hash of the secret + the random number.

The *but also* part, which is the establishment of a session key, is a bit hand-wavy. Since both side already have a common secret, why do you need a session key, and not just use the common secret as a session key?

Note that this question has nothing to do with public key systems or asymmetric encryption or digital signature. In this case, both sides know the same secret.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do you need to encrypt symmetric key?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53638/why-do-you-need-to-encrypt-symmetric-key)